# xampp-control-panel import error missing gtk on mac os x lion

Tags: xampp, osx-mountain-lion, importerror

I installed XAMPP 1.8.3 on Mac OS X Lion (10.8.5). I'm trying to launch xampp-control-panel in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/xampp-control-panel. 
It asks that I run xampp-control-panel application as root. I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xampp-control-panel.py", line 18, in 
    import gtk
ImportError: No module named gtk

I have only Apple's pre-installed Python. The command:
$ which python
outputs /usr/bin/python. I haven't installed any other Python distribution.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little old but I recently faced it as well. I found this solution,[How to start xampp gui](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529500/how-to-start-xampp-gui) and this guide [Xampp Installation in Ubuntu](https://emuhendis.wordpress.com/2009/07/19/ubuntuda-xampp-server-kurulumu/) both of which did not work for me to run the Gui. So I put them them here in case they might help some of you.

For now, I use the following commands to start and stop XAMPP,

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
```